# Using the non-static method getUI().getPage() return an error : IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, vaadin, illegalargumentexception

I've a basic question. 
I'm using Vaadin 8.

When I use :

```
Page.getCurrent().setTitle(IStringConstants.HOMEPAGE_LABEL);
```

This is working without issue.

And, when I use

```
 getUI().getPage().setTitle(IStringConstants.HOMEPAGE_LABEL);
```

I receive an error :`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of {0}. The constructor threw an exception.`

Because `getUI()` return `null`.

My code is pretty simple, in my home page :

```
public class HomepageView extends CustomComponent implements View {
 public HomepageView() {
    getUI().getPage().setTitle(IStringConstants.HOMEPAGE_LABEL);
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    setCompositionRoot(layout);
 }
}
```

And my UI is :

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class myUI extends UI {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("", HomepageView.class);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "myUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = myUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class myUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUI()` returns null in your case, because the instance you are creating has no parent yet. The parent is set when you add your HomepageView Component to a layout or Panel for instance. `getUI()` traverses the parents up to the UI root or returns null no such parent is found. You can call `getUI().getPage().setTitle(IStringConstants.HOMEPAGE_LABEL);` in the attach listener:

```
public HomepageView() {
    this.addAttachListener(e -> {
        getUI().getPage().setTitle(IStringConstants.HOMEPAGE_LABEL);
    });
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    setCompositionRoot(layout);

    // show something
    layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));
}
```

**Edit**

As Morfic pointed out the more common and cleaner solution would be to use the View's enter method instead of the constructor. As you can see the listener is not necessary anymore, since the component already got attached to the UI tree:

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    getUI().getPage().setTitle("This is a title");
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    setCompositionRoot(layout);
    layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still confuse. About your first point : "The parent is set when you add your HomepageView Component to a layout or Panel for instance. ". Is it about adding : `VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(); layout.setSizeFull(); setCompositionRoot(layout);` in the HomepageView constructor?

Comment: That's right. Furthermore, because your component implements View, I assume you register it with the Navigator. Then on navigate your component is automatically attached to a component container by the Navigator. That is the Navigator calls something like `panel.setContent(yourComponent)`

Comment: I edited the code in the post. The homepageview should works like that?Because, it's not working for me... What do I miss? Thanks for your help. I know, it's a basic question ..

Comment: I created your app on my computer and it worked. I edited my answer and added a label in the code, so there's actually some content on the page. Please try again and let me know if there are still errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, this is a workarround like using the `Page.getCurrent().setTitle`. Is it enough clean? I'm looking for a clean code/ solution. With your solution, I should use the attachListener all the time. I'm using the Session in other view like : `getUI().getSession().setAttribute("token", user.getToken());`, So I need to add the attach listener again?

Comment: @Bob the main problem is that you're trying to get the parent in the child constructor which is not logically possible. Only after the object is constructed can it be added as a child. Just like you can't be a parent untill your baby is born, you're not yet a parent during the 9 monts of pregnancy, get it? :-). In your case, if you move the line from the constructor to the `enter` method, it should be just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Morfic, So the good solution is to create an instance variable and set the value in the enter ? Because, I want to use the getUI() in the View (Set session and get session values for example)

Comment: @Bob Not sure what you mean by `create an instance variable`, but simply put, use `getUI()` outside constructor calls and use the constructor just to initialize your components with fields and values. Also it makes sense to change the title when actually switching to the view. For example if you have 3 views and all of them set a different title, which one would you like to see? I bet it's the one relative to the currently displayed view, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Comment: Thanks both of us ! Very clear explaination and clean one :)

Comment: @Morfic, And if I don't implement a View? I just herit the CustomComponent? I cannot override enter()

Comment: @Bob you'll have to think about something else, depending on your scenario. I don't think there is one solution that can apply to everything...